# Execute Immediate?

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

Why do we use `execute immediate` command in PL/SQL?

I'm looking at some procedures written by a previous colleague, and I see that the person has used `execute immediate` a lot many time to log the progress of the procedure and also when truncating the tables.

My question is why would he do so? Can we not just truncate tables just like that in pl/sql proc?

Comment: Can you post an example of the use of EXECUTE IMMEDIATE to log messages? That's sounds peculiar. (Whereas the use for TRUNCATE is expected: TRUNCATE is DDL and we can't execute DDL in PL/SQL except through special measures).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from executing DDL from PL/SQL (which you've already been told), `execute immediate` is used to run **dynamic SQL**. What would that be? Creating statements that depend on information that is not known at the time you're creating the PL/SQL procedure. For example, selecting from several tables in your schema:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_str varchar2(1000);
  3    l_cnt number;
  4  begin
  5    for cur_r in (select table_name from user_tables
  6                  where table_name in ('EMP', 'DEPT', 'BONUS')
  7                 )
  8    loop
  9      l_str := 'select count(*) from ' || cur_r.table_name;
 10      execute immediate l_str into l_cnt;
 11      dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.table_name ||': '|| l_cnt);
 12    end loop;
 13  end;
 14  /
BONUS: 0
DEPT: 4
EMP: 14

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Similarly, you might create a function that uses table (or column) names *dynamically*, e.g.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_cnt (par_table_name in varchar2)
  2    return number
  3  is
  4    l_str varchar2(1000);
  5    l_cnt number;
  6  begin
  7    l_str := 'select count(*) from ' || dbms_assert.sql_object_name(par_table_name);
  8    execute immediate l_str into l_cnt;
  9    return l_cnt;
 10  end;
 11  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_cnt('emp') from dual;

F_CNT('EMP')
------------
          14

SQL>
```

Comment: +1. I am glad you had time and will to give broader answer. I went directly after OPs DDL struggles. But IMO this question is already answered in Oracle docs.

Comment: Really appreciate your detailed response on this (with additional information).

Answer (score 4):

Oracle wouldn't allow execution of DDL inside executable block. This is not allowed

```
begin
    alter table . . . 
end;
```

Originally Oracle had `SYS.DBMS_DDL` package to do this job. But it was cumbersome to use, so oracle introduced `execute immediate` circa v9.